# Mysql Cascade on update does not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, cascade, autocommit

I am developing an application in java. With this application, I want to store data about students and payments so I decided to construct a database with MySQL.

I created a schema with two tables`(students,payments)`.

The `students` table has many columns, one of which is called `student_id` and is the primary key.

The `payments` table has many columns one of which is called `payment_id`(Primary key) and `student_id` which is a foreign key from the primary key of `students` table.

I set the foreign key to `cascade` on `Update`, so if i update a value in the `student_id` column in `students` table the value will be updated automatically in the column `student_id` in `payments` table. The problem is that when i change a value in a row at the `student_id` column in `students` table I can see that the changes have been applied through a select query(SELECT * FROM students) in `students` table. But when i execute a select query(SELECT * FROM payments) in  `payments` table it seems that the changes have not been applied in the column `students_id`. Please note that `autocommit` is enabled. Only when I commit the `select` execution on `payments` table will show the right results(the updated row).

Comment: What do you mean by "commit the select execution on payments"?

Comment: I mean that I turn off autocommit and after the query I add the word 'COMMIT'.

Comment: Not clear question. Is autocommit enabled or disabled? Do you run these queries and update statements from one connection or from different ones?

Comment: And why do you need to update a `student_id`? If it's an auto-generated value, it should stay put and never changed.

Comment: Guys finally solved the problem!!!The name of Schema contained "-" which is not recommended. Mysql recommends that we should use only alpha-numeric characters. Space should be avoided and be replaced by _.  Now cascade on Update works perfectly and i get the right results!!!